# How large of testing sample size is sufficient for testing a new method?

Tags: statistics, evaluation

I have developed a new image segmentation technique, and now I want to evaluate the performance. I am wondering how many sample do I need to perform the evaluation? In other words, how large is the testing sample set is sufficient in order to evaluate the new method? Any theory backup for that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are standard computer vision datasets to benchmark segmentation. Example: http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/Research/Projects/CS/vision/bsds/ 
You would have to report how your algorithm performs on these. Considering that the number of all possible images in the world is pretty big, these would constitute a good sample. ;-)